# how to select the parent id then grandparent id in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to click a button in my webpage that has a dynamically generated number as part of the ID. So I am avoiding the ID locator and trying to click the button based on class name. The following works in the console to locate the element:

```
$('span.Name').parent().parent().find('a.QuoteGridBuy').click()
```

but how can I translate this to c# for selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..` to go to parent element

```
IWebElement toClick = baseElement.FindElement(By.Xpath("../.."));
toClick.Click();
```

Or full `xpath`

```
IWebElement toClick = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@class='Name']/../../"));
toClick.Click();
```

You can also find the element by partial id using `CssSelector`

```
IWebElement toClick = baseElement.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id*='fixedIdPart']"));
toClick.Click();
```

Comment: I'm using the following to find the element via XPath - FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='span.Name']/../../" but I am getting back The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@class='span.Name']/../../ because of the following error: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression. Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Pixie The class name is wrong. `span` is the tag not part of the class name. `FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='Name']/../../")`